# Is there a way to iterate over each file in a folder before copy in Python?

Tags: python, excel, copy, openpyxl, shutil

Each picture with .png extn in a X folder has to be copied, compare to values in excel and paste to different folder Y based on a condition. Here are my 2 problems,

1. My script is copying all the images in the folder X and pastes to Y. Is there a way to iterate through each images in folder X and based on if condition paste to Y folder.
2. Is there a way to compare 2 columns in excel for ex: The excel has column A '1.jpeg' and column B as letter 'B', IF 1.JPEG = B then copy the file 1.jpeg and put in b folder, if 1.peg = C, then copy 1.jpeg and put in C folder etc.

Here is my current code,

```
source = r"C:\\Users\\Downloads\\From\\"
> destination_B = r"C:\\Users\\Downloads\\From\\Groups\\B"
> destination_C = r"C:\\Users\\Downloads\\From\\Groups\\C"
> 
> 
> inputExcelFile = "Script.xlsx"
> 
> newWorkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(inputExcelFile)
> 
> firstWorksheet = newWorkbook\["Sheet1"\]
> 
> extensionList = ("jpg", "png")
> 
> GroupName_b = "B"
> GroupName_c = "C"
> 
> for imageName in os.listdir(source):
    if imageName.endswith(extensionList):
>        for column_data1 in firstWorksheet\["A"\]:
>         x = column_data1.value
>        for column_data2 in firstWorksheet\["B"\]:
>         y = column_data2.value
>         if GroupName_c == y and imageName == x:
>         shutil.copy(imageName, destination_C)
>         else:
>         print("Failed")
```

here shutil.copy(imageName, destination_C) copied the whole folder images instead of checking the condition in excel and copy only if 1.png in col A = letter "B" in col B.

here if GroupName_c == y and imageName == x: is my code which doesn't work for my 2nd problem.

Excel sheet:

[image: excel sheet sample image]

Comment: Your code is incomplete (no imports, not a [mcve]), it doesn't compile with all the `>`s and the messed up indentation... make it easy to help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way :

```
import shutil
from openpyxl import load_workbook

d = dict(load_workbook("Script.xlsx")["Sheet1"].values)

for img, dst in d.items():
    if dst in subs: # in case the column B has more subfolders
        shutil.copy(source / img, source / "Groups" / dst / img)
```

Result :

```
From
┣━━ 33_67013_7961.png
┣━━ 38_62468_5866.jpg
┣━━ 39_12945_1208.png
┣━━ 49_99346_6890.jpg
┣━━ 55_41444_3350.png
┣━━ 56_68334_4267.jpg
┣━━ 60_73375_1649.png
┣━━ 64_18254_4617.jpg
┣━━ 70_01840_1528.png
┣━━ 96_12429_4104.jpg
┣━━ Groups
┃   ┣━━ B
┃   ┃   ┣━━ 39_12945_1208.png
┃   ┃   ┣━━ 49_99346_6890.jpg
┃   ┃   ┣━━ 55_41444_3350.png
┃   ┃   ┣━━ 56_68334_4267.jpg
┃   ┃   ┣━━ 60_73375_1649.png
┃   ┃   ┣━━ 64_18254_4617.jpg
┃   ┃   ┗━━ 70_01840_1528.png
┃   ┗━━ C
┃       ┣━━ 33_67013_7961.png
┃       ┣━━ 38_62468_5866.jpg
┃       ┗━━ 96_12429_4104.jpg
Script.xlsx
```

---

***Used config :***

[image]

```
from pathlib import Path
subs = ["B", "C"]; source = Path("From")

for s in subs:
    (source / "Groups" / s).mkdir(parents=True)

import random; random.seed(0)

images = [
    f"{random.randint(0, 99):02}_{random.randint(0, 99999):05}"
    f"_{random.randint(0, 9999):04}.{random.choice(['jpg', 'png'])}"
    for _ in range(10)
]

for i in images:
    with open(source / i, "w") as f:
        pass

from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook(); wb["Sheet"].title = "Sheet1"

for i in images:
    wb["Sheet1"].append([i, random.choice(subs)])
    
wb.save("Script.xlsx")
```